# Regex wildcard page rule for redirecting trailing slash

Tags: regex, cloudflare

trying to redirect all trailing slash urls to non trailing slash on Cloudflare using a redirect page rule. I’m new to regex, can anyone help? Thanks

Tried: *example.com/*

To

*example.com/$2

But had no idea what I was doing

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need more than one rule to do this in a safe and sound way:

```
https://example.com/*/ to https://example.com/$1 
https://example.com/*/?* to https://example.com/$1?$2
```

The first page rule is used to redirect sub-pages with a trailing slash; the second is used to redirect sub-pages with a query string. The same might be required for the base URL

```
https://example.com/ to https://example.com 
https://example.com/?* to https://example.com?$1
```

However, you might be better off using a [.htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) file if your website is running on Apache like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect non-directories to URL without trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you do not care about directories simply remove the RewriteCond.

Comment: Thanks so much! Running on github pages so not on Apache. Was considering moving to hosting though, just trying to keep things free for now. Kind of you to answer, much appreciated 

Comment: Unfortunately the solution didn't work :( The page wouldn't load because of to many redirects. I'm sacking the whole thing and following your second suggestion of moving to hosting with Apache. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create such redirect URL with the following settings:

[image: Trailing slash removal using cloudlfare]

URL: `https://example.com/*/`

Destination URL: `https://example.com/$1`